# How to do http get call after a condition is satified and if not retry and call again in angular 4

Tags: angular, reactjs

I am updating a form if clicked on different page. I am listing out the values in a different page. Issue is after values are changed and if i click the list page, values wont be updated by the time get call is made in list page.

Ex: i have variable while updating service, ie. saveFunction. After it is updated saveFuction = null.

In listing service call ,
 return this.http.get(`${this.url}netwealth`, this.requestOption)
                      .map((r: Response) => r.json());

I want to check the variable saveFunction is null, then  call http.get in listing service, if not delay for sometime and try again. I am able to get saveFunciton variable. In the below code, i am doing http.get before the condition is checked. Due to this http.get is called many times. I am looking for how to   check the condition first and then do http.get.

```
public GetNetWealth(): Observable<any> { 
 return Observable.create((o: Observer<any>) => {
        let saveFunction = this.detailService.savefunction;
        this.http.get(`${this.url}netwealth`, this.requestOption)
            .map((r: Response) => r.json())
            .subscribe((result) => {
                if (saveFunction) {
                    setTimeout({}, 2000);
                    o.error('retry');
                } else {
                    o.next(result);
                    o.complete();
                }

            },
            error => o.error(error)
            );
    }).retryWhen((errors) => {
        return errors.map(error => {
            return true;
        }
        );
    }).delay(1000);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to validate the condition, then call http.get using Observables.

```
return Observable.create((o: Observer<any>) => {
        let isCompleted = this.detailService.hasLastSaveCompleted;

        if (!isCompleted) {
            o.error('prevSaveNotCompleted');
        } else {
            this.http.get(`${this.url}test`, this.requestOption)
                .map((r: Response) => r.json())
                .subscribe((result) => {
                    o.next(result);
                    o.complete();
                },
                error => o.error(error)
                );
        }
    }).retryWhen((errors) => {
        return errors.map(error => {

            if (error !== 'prevSaveNotCompleted') {
                throw new Error(error);
            }

            return true;
        }).delay(200);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using while loop as there is no other way to wait JS execution.

```
isInProgress: boolean = false;

listing(netwealth) {
    while(this.isInProgress) {
        // Do nothing
    }
    this.isInProgress = true;
    return this.http.get(${this.url}netwealth, this.requestOption)
                .map((r: Response) => {
                    return r.json();
                    this.isInProgress = false;
                });
}
```

But better if you can redesign your implementation by using `Subject` & `Observable`.

**Solution 2**

```
isInProgress: boolean = false;

inProgresssubject = new Subject<any>();

let pendingRequests: any[] = [];

updateIsProgress(value) {
    this.inProgresssubject.next(value);
}

getUpdateProgress(): Observable<any> {
    return this.inProgresssubject.asObservable();
}

this.getUpdateProgress().subscribe(isInProgress => { 
    this.isInProgress = this.isInProgress || isInProgress;
    if(!this.isInProgress && pendingRequests.length > 0) {
        let newValue = this.pendingRequests.shift();
        // Update newValue on server && also call this.updateIsProgress(true);
    }
});

updateDataOnServer(newValue) {
    if(isInProgress) {
        this.pendingRequests.add(newValue);
    } else {
        // Update newValue on server && also call this.updateIsProgress(true);
    }
}
```

2nd solution is not completed one but will give you idea how to proceed.

Comment: Could you please provide an example ?

Comment: @bs25 here you can find it http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject. It's not according to your requirement but you can have idea about terms. Would suggest do refactor whenever you get time. Till then you can use above solution.

Comment: It went on to infinite loop with while loop.  Is it possible to implement using Observable.create ?

Comment: are you sure `this.saveFunction` is being updated?
You can maintain a queue for all future request when `saveFunction` is `true` and make `saveFunction` as observable so that whever the value is being updated you can check if anything is in queue to execute. If there is any pending request just complete it. If you want I can write the code for you.

Comment: I have updated my answer for 1st solution, if still you are not able to solve post your code or better create stackblitz.

Comment: I have  updated my question.Was able to retry observable. But i want to implement before http get call